# Using InitialLOBFetchSize with EntityFramework

Tags: oracle, performance, entity-framework

I've got an **Oracle** database that I access through *Entity Framework* and I am seeing a performance hit on selects where I hit tables with **CLOB** columns in them.

If I break out the query generated by *Entity Framework* I get similar results when simply calling `ExecuteReader` using an `OracleCommand`, but I can improve performance a lot by setting `InitialLOBFetchSize` to **-1** on the `OracleCommand`.

I would like to do the same for *Entity Framework*.

How do I tell *Entity Framework* to set `InitialLOBFetchSize` to -1?

This is for *Entity Framework* 4.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem few years ago and I ended up using a wrapped OracleConnection, OracleCommand, DbProviderFactory and other ADO.NET classes, and Entity Framework provider so any operation EF does with instances of these classes I was able to inject any functionality in or change the command or connection configuration.